# A formula of Riemannian metric and its determinant

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, matrix-calculus

Let $g_{ij}$ be a Riemannian metric of a Riemannian manifold, prove:

$$ g^{ij}\frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial x^k}=\frac{1}{G}\frac{\partial G}{\partial x^k},\quad G=\det(g_{ij}),\quad  g^{ij}=g_{ij}^{-1}$$
I have tested the case $i,j\leq 2$, it's correct, but in the general case, I think I lack the suitable skill to prove it. So can someone help me?

Comment: for any (non singular) matrix $A$: $\det(A)=e^{tr(\log(A)) } $

Comment: but how to define $log(A)$?

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of the determinant is [given by Jacobi's formula](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/214908/proof-for-the-derivative-of-the-determinant-of-a-matrix):
$$ \partial_k \det(g) = \det(g)\,\text{tr}\left( g^{-1}\partial_kg \right) $$
This simplifies nicely in indicial form:
\begin{align} \partial_k \det(g) &= \det(g)g^{\alpha\beta}\partial_kg_{\beta\gamma}\delta_\alpha^\gamma\\
&= \det(g)g^{\alpha\beta}\partial_kg_{\beta\alpha}\\
&= \det(g)g^{ij}\partial_kg_{ij}\\
\end{align}
Therefore, we get: $$ \frac{1}{G}\frac{\partial G}{\partial x^k}=
\frac{1}{\det(g)}\partial_k\det({g}) =
g^{ij}\partial_kg_{ij} = g^{ij}\frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial x^k}
$$